# One to one Video call with voice in Open TokBox : Android, dotNET

Tags: android, .net, opentok, tokbox

I want to setup One to one Video with voice call using Open TokBox. I want to setup it in Android and Server Side is dotNET. I found sample project and it is working fine but it is like multi broadcasting. And It finds if any user is online.
Rather than this, I want that One user call another user from Android Device. And if that another user is online then he gets notification about call else it shows offline user. This can happen with many users same way.
Its like skype but only one to one. So, as I know I will need to create new session id at dotNET server side.
Please help me to perform this task perfectly.

Comment: You got any solution?

Comment: @Aamirkhan, I am trying to make it myself.

Comment: You can make use of Signaling https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/signaling/android/